NASDAQ ITCH Order Executed With Price Message
I'm building a basic feed handler with the NASDAQ ITCH sample data and I'm a little confused on Order Execution With Price.
From the decoded sample data I've pulled out message type C (section 1.4.2) for a single stock (MSFT).
All messages of this type show orders on the bid experiencing negative price change and ask, positive - this makes sense given reg-nms best execution rules i.e. if there is a different execution price you'd expect it to be a better one given the rules.
My question is: how does this happen mechanically? What are the scenarios where you'd get filled at a better price?
My thinking is the following:

Order 1 is 10 shares at best bid of 100 and is the only order in the queue.
Order 2 is 10 shares at 99.
Order 3 is from an aggressive seller, and crosses the spread to sell 15 shares at 99.

Is order 1 effectively bumped to the front of the order queue the level below and executed at 99 against order 3, then the remainder of order 3 is executed against order 2 just leaving the 5 shares from order 2 at the best bid of 99?
If so is this because only limit orders are subject to best ex and therefore if an aggressive order shows up, that order isn't entitled to sell at 100 first and then 99?
Really keen to understand the mechanics of how this happens, cheers!
